# Magento 2.3.5 - Undefined property: Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor::$_carrierFactory on Shipping Method

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I am getting the error message in the browser when i try to checkout:

```
Undefined property: Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor::$_carrierFactory in/app/code/Wyomind/EstimatedDeliveryDate/Plugin/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 91 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5fc3d22bf281f; Message: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor::$_carrierFactory in /app/code/Wyomind/EstimatedDeliveryDate/Plugin/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 91 at /vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined property: Magento\\Quote\\Model\\Quote\\Address\\Interceptor::$_carrierFactory in /app/code/Wyomind/EstimatedDeliveryDate/Plugin/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php on line 91 at /vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

It's not showing any shipping method so i can't checkout. I have tried to add a variable above the constructor:

```
protected $_carrierFactory;
```

but it's not working.

Code in **/app/code/Wyomind/EstimatedDeliveryDate/Plugin/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php** is

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright © 2019 Wyomind. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Wyomind\EstimatedDeliveryDate\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote;

/**
 * Class Address
 * @package Wyomind\EstimatedDeliveryDate\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote
 */
class Address
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $_storeManager;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder
     */
    private $_jsonDecoder;
    /**
     * @var \Wyomind\Core\Helper\Data
     */
    private $_coreHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart
     */
    private $_checkoutCart;
    /**
     * @var \Wyomind\EstimatedDeliveryDate\Helper\Data
     */
    private $_helperData;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration
     */
    private $_productConfigurationHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    private $_productModel;

    /**
     * Address constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder $jsonDecoder
     * @param \Wyomind\Core\Helper\Data $coreHelper
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $checkoutCart
     * @param \Wyomind\EstimatedDeliveryDate\Helper\Data $helperData
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfigurationHelper
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel
     */
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Json\Decoder $jsonDecoder, \Wyomind\Core\Helper\Data $coreHelper,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $checkoutCart,
            \Wyomind\EstimatedDeliveryDate\Helper\Data $helperData,
            \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Configuration $productConfigurationHelper,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel)
    {

        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->_coreHelper = $coreHelper;
        $this->_checkoutCart = $checkoutCart;
        $this->_helperData = $helperData;
        $this->_productConfigurationHelper = $productConfigurationHelper;
        $this->_productModel = $productModel;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $subject
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @return array
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function aroundGetGroupedAllShippingRates(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $subject,
                                                     \Closure $proceed)
    {
        $rates = [];

        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $jsonShipping = $this->_jsonDecoder->decode($this->_coreHelper->getStoreConfig("estimateddeliverydate/shipping/json", $storeId));
        $items = $subject->getQuote()->getAllItems();

        foreach ($subject->getShippingRatesCollection() as $rate) {
            if (!$rate->isDeleted() && $subject->_carrierFactory->get($rate->getCarrier())) {
                if (!isset($rates[$rate->getCarrier()])) {
                    $rates[$rate->getCarrier()] = [];
                }

                $code = $rate->getCode();

                $message = null;
                foreach ($jsonShipping as $rule) {
                    if (preg_match("#" . $rule['code'] . "#", $code)) {
                        $leadtime = array();
                        foreach ($items as $item) {
                            $options = $this->_productConfigurationHelper->getCustomOptions($item);
                            $product = $this->_productModel->loadByAttribute("sku", $item->getSku());
                            if (!$product) {
                                $id = $item->getProductId();
                                $product = $this->_productModel->load($id);
                            }
                            if ($product) {
                                $add = $this->_helperData->parseFromTo($rule["leadtime"]);
                                $additional = $this->_helperData->getCustomOptions($options, $storeId);
                                $leadtime[] = $this->_helperData->getLeadTimes($product, -1, $storeId, $additional[0], $additional[1], $item->getQty(), $add);
                            }
                        }
                        $range = $this->_helperData->getLeadTimeRange($leadtime);

                        $message = $this->_helperData->renderCartMessage($range, $storeId, "cart", $rule["message"]);

                        $rate->setMethodTitle(str_replace(["{{title}}"], [$rate->getMethodTitle()], strip_tags($message)));

                        break;
                    }
                }
                $rates[$rate->getCarrier()][] = $rate;
                $rates[$rate->getCarrier()][0]->carrier_sort_order = $subject->_carrierFactory->get(
                                $rate->getCarrier()
                        )->getSortOrder();
            }
        }
        uasort($rates, [$this, '_sortRates']);

        return $rates;
    }

    /**
     * @param $firstItem
     * @param $secondItem
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _sortRates($firstItem, $secondItem)
    {
        if ((int) $firstItem[0]->carrier_sort_order < (int) $secondItem[0]->carrier_sort_order) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ((int) $firstItem[0]->carrier_sort_order > (int) $secondItem[0]->carrier_sort_order) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Someone can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The plugin seems to be incompatible with your Magento version. Please contact the vendor of the plugin and get an appropriate version. The accessed property should be in the subject not in your plugin i.e. class `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address` but that variable has changed from `protected $_carrierFactory;` to `private $carrierFactory;`

Comment: @HelgeB . It's working good with the current Magento version before (we didn't make any updates with the plugin or Magento version for sure). Suddenly it didn't work and we didn't know what we did. That's log error for our problem. So we guess this caused by changing something that's wrong in Magento Backend (or in core) with the DPD Carrier or Wyomind Estimated Delivery Date plugin. Thank you for your comment!